I see two approaches to npgsql prepares. Trying to understand the differences
I have been exploring how to access Postgres from C#.  When using prepared statements ( which I almost always want to do) the website recommends the following:

Create a connection the db  NpgsqlConnection con.
Define my string command "Insert into employee ( employeenum,name,email) VALUES (@empnum, @empname, @email ) returning ID";
3 .Create a NpgsqlCommand using the command string
Create a NpgSqlParamater defining the data type for each replaceable parameter;
Call Prepare on the command

When ready to execute

Set the Value portion of each NpgsqlParamater to the correct value
Call the appropriate Execute statement ( ExecuteScaler, ExecuteNonQuery, etc)
Deal with the reply

It occurred to me that I could simply choose to use SQL syntax when preparing,  IE
1 Create a connection to the db NpgsqlConneciton con
2. Define my string command "PREPARE insertemployee ( varchar, varchar, varchar) AS INSERT into Employee ( employeenum, name, email)  VALUES ($1, $2, $3 ) RETURNING ID"";
3, Create a NpgSQL command using the command string.
4. Execute the command
When ready to execute I would
1 Create a command string with the appropriate parameters  IE "Execute insertemployee('', 'value2', 'value3')
2.Create a NpgsqlCommand with that command string
3 Execute the command and deal with the reply.
My questions:   If the first method is preferred, why is it better than the second method?
If I were to look at the commands sent over the wire to the server, would they be substantially different?
Thanks.

Using NpgsqlCommand.Prepare() is slightly more efficient, as you can retain a reference to an NpgsqlCommand and reexecute it with different parameters. If you create an NpgsqlCommand each time for EXECUTE, there's a bit more overhead there.
But in practice, the difference should be negligible for almost all applications and it wouldn't matter.
